Setting up Global Styles in MUI
I am currently using @mui/styles to set Global Styles
const useStyles = makeStyles<Theme, { ... }>(
  () =>
    createStyles({
      "@global": {
        html: {
          ...
        },
      },
    }),
  { name: "..." }
);

  const styleProps = ...;

  useStyles(styleProps);

I am migrating to React 18 and need to get off MUI styles so I wonder what is the new proper syntax/libraries I should use.
